# ¿Por qué me suelta error de sintaxis?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy programando en Netbeans 8.1 con Python 3.5 y me suelta el siguiente error.

> while len(Conjunto) <= M-1:
>           ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax>

He intentado de todo, pero no veo el error en ningún nado.

Aquí está mi código:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
       def ConR(self):
         Conjunto = ["A"]
         Dict = {"A":1}
         Cont = 1
         Aux=None
         AUX=None
         Add = None
         OK=False
         M=0
         print(len(Conjunto)+1)
         while OK == False:
            #try:
                M = int( (input("Ingrese n : ") ) 
                while len(Conjunto)<=M-1:
                        Add = input("Ingrese el Elemento N\xfamero " + str(Cont) + " : ")
                        if Add in Conjunto:
                                    Aux = Dict.get(Add)
                                    AUX = Aux + 1
                                    Dict.update({Add:AUX})
                                    print(Dict)
                                    Conjunto.append(Add)
                                    Cont+=1
                        else:
                            Conjunto.append(Add)
                            Dict.update({Add:1})
                            Cont+=1
                        M = factorial(M)
                        print("Hay " + str(M) + " Posibles Permutaciones con Repetici\xf3n")
                        OK = True
            #except:
                print("Ha ocurrido un error   :(")
                print("\xbfSegugo de que has introducido un n\xfamero?")
         return M

    ConR(self)
```

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes el `try...except` comentado? Eso te debería lanzar un error de indentación al menos. Parece que netbeans no está pillando eso correctamente.

Comment: Si no los comento, no veo los errores. Ya probé con Geany, Pycharm y varios compiladores online. Todos me sueltan el mismo error.

Answer (score 3):

Ese error en particular `while len(Conjunto) <= M-1: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax>` es porque la sentencia anterior le falta un paréntesis (el que cierra la función `int`)

Es decir quedaría así: `int((input("Ingrese n : ")))`

Answer (score 1):

El error :

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax>

define un error de sintaxis, en ocasiones no es provocado en la misma linea, puede encontrarse en una anterior de código,

```
..
  M = int( (input("Ingrese n : ") ) 
  while len(Conjunto)<=M-1:
..
```

como ya se comentó en la línea anterior falta agregar un parentesís de cierre para la función **[int()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)** :

```
 M = int( (input("Ingrese n : ") ) )
```